# How do I check wether a time series is weakly dependent?

Tags: regression, time-series, least-squares, independence

If I understood correctly **weak dependence** is one of the assumptions that has to be met when estimating a linear regression model for time series data by ***Ordinary Least Squares***.

There are tests and techniques to check wether the other assumptions, such as stationarity or no perfect multicollinearity, are met. For some reason, I did not come across any concrete method to check wether a time series is weakly dependent or not.

Furthermore, none of the scientific papers I have read touches this topic (econometric models for electricity prices/electricity consumption etc.) *At most* the authors seem to test for things like multicollinearity. I am just an undergrad student writing his bachelor thesis now, so I probably have a rather limited understanding of the topic, but sometimes authors do not even seem to care about certain conditions as specific models are misspecified/do not meet certain assumptions in such an obvious way.

Anyhow, to conclude - I would like to test wether a time series is weakly dependent or not and I did not find any statistical method to do this. An intuitive idea of mine was to just look at the a*utocorrelation function* of the given time series. If the function seems to decline and eventually hits zero, I would assume the time series is weakly dependent. Is this approach correct?

Thank you in advance. Stack Exchange has been of great help so far! Glad I have come across this website.

Comment: Weak dependence is a catch-all term for an assumption that describes an entire family of dependence behaviours. What they all have in common is -- roughly speaking -- that the error dies out quickly enough in time to still make OLS consistent. They encompass vastly different stochastic processes such as *Linear Processes*, *Near-Epoch Dependence* or *Martingale Difference Sequences*. Most of these are pretty much un-testable (Near-Epoch Dependence for instance), and so unless you assume a *specific* form of weak dependence, testing for generic 'weak dependence' is not possible.

Comment: "Weakly correlated" and weakly dependent are different situations, so as uncorrelated and independent are.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @JeremiasK and Viktor. My intuitive approach for testing wether a time series is weakly dependent or not was based on Wooldridge (2013). In his textbooks he says, that intuitively one can say a time series is weakly dependent when "the correlation between xt and xt+h goes to 0 "sufficiently quickly" as h approaches infinity". To my understanding, this is exactly what I would be able to perceive by looking at the acf plot.

Comment: Well, if you are happy with a rough diagnostic, this is certainly a good way to go about it. But as @Viktor pointed out, your dependence might not necessarily correspond to correlation. (Think for example of GARCH-type models.)

Comment: Alright, I guess for my purposes the "simple" notion of weak dependence is sufficient (also: I am estimating a linear regression model by OLS and QR so I guess the notion is sufficient anyways). Thank you.